# How do you call someone who would emberrass hisself for items?

Tags: word-usage

Is there a word to describe a person, that would embarrass hisself to obtain items?

Let`s say person A would give person B something very expensive, if person B would emberrass hisself in public.
How would you call person B?

Comment: Is there a word for this in your language, or any other language that you know?   Have you tried a bilingual dictionary?  If there is no word in your language, can you explain why you need this word in English?

Comment: Also, free and easy to use spellcheckers should be used to avoid spelling mistakes.  Everybody makes spelling mistakes, but most are easy for your computer or phone to detect.

Answer (score 0):

Not especially for items but for money in general:
**A money sucker**

From the urban dictionary (which you should take with a gran or rather truck load of salt):

> Someone who urges to get money so badly that would be willing to to
>   sell his own mother for pennies.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=money%20sucker

Answer (score 0):

You could use a broad [definition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/whore) of the word

> **whore**
>   NOUN
>
> **1.2** A person who is regarded as willing to do anything to get a particular thing.
>
> - *he's a shameless publicity whore*
> - *I wonder if I would be a total sponsor whore: would I wear whatever someone put in front of me for a few dollars?*